# How can I use prefix query on Korean word in Elasticsearch?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, normalization, icu

I've been doing well using Elasticsearch on "English" documents.
However, I got stuck on prefix query when using "**Korean**" words.

In details, a document contains word such as `"한글"` and I want to get the document using prefix query with search term not only `"한"` but also `"ㅎ"`.

I could not do that using default settings.
I saw that it's related to `icu_normalizer` or `nfd decomposition` or something else.
But I could not totally understand the way I have to do to get the result "한글" using "ㅎ" search term.

Is there anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code helps you.

```
curl -XPUT '127.0.0.1:9200/test' -d '{
  "settings" : {
    "analysis": {
      "tokenizer" : {
        "autocomplete_tokenizer" : {
          "type" : "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram" : "1",
          "max_gram" : "30",
          "token_chars": ["letter", "digit"]
        }
      },
      "char_filter" : {
        "nfd_normalizer" : {
          "type" : "icu_normalizer",
          "name": "nfc",
          "mode": "decompose"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": ["nfd_normalizer"],
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete_tokenizer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl '127.0.0.1:9200/test/_analyze?pretty=1&analyzer=autocomplete_analyzer' -d '아버지가 방에 들어가신다. 태권-V'
```

Comment: Use autocomplete_tokenizer when indexing only. When querying, you can use different tokenizer & nfd filter